# Kendo error after upgrading to Dotnet Core 1.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, kendo-ui

Since upgrading to Core Final 1.0 release, I get the following error when running the MVC site:
On line 59 while running services.AddKendo().

```
Line 57: services.AddMvc();  
Line 58: // Register UI for ASP.NET MVC helpers  
Line 59: services.AddKendo();  
Line 60:  
Line 61: // Addapplication services.
```

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could
> not load type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddKendo(IServiceCollection
> services)    at
> zepdata.com.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in
> PATH\Startup.cs:line 59    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[]
> parameters)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object
> instance, IServiceCollection exportServices)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IServiceCollection
> services)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
> services)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

I upgraded VS 2015 Update 3 and Dotnet Core 1.0.

Comment: If it's any help, I'm running into this same error with a different nuget package (signalr rc2). Sounds like some names were changed around for DI in core 1, and so packages will need to be updated accordingly: https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/412

Comment: I find that most Kendo errors happen when people don't pay attention to distance between them and their opponent

AHAAHAHA I'M FUNNY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Kendo.Mvc 2016.2.630 internal build available that seems to fix this issue. Wasn't able to find it on their nuget site, but if you log in to your telerik account and go to your product downloads, it should be listed there under internal builds.

The nupkg is in \wrappers\aspnetmvc\Binaries\Mvc6

(But still problems with grid)

From this: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/1856

Comment: I got the new version, and it does seem to work, but fails on displaying data on the grid.  I posted a new question related to this. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138399/aspnet-core-1-0-rtm-kendo-grid-not-displaying-data)

Answer (score 1):

Replace services.AddKendo() with its implementation:

```cs
foreach (ServiceDescriptor service in Kendo.Mvc.KendoServices.GetServices())
    services.Add(service);
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

It's required since latest version of Kendo was compiled for aspnetcore-rc2. In aspnet 1.0 some classes were renamed so Kendo cannot find them.

https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/187

Comment: Yes, application is started, but same exception occurs later during page loading with kendo controls.

Comment: This does help with this specific error, but a lot of other things fail after that.  For instance a Read Action on a Kendo grid.  Seems like Telerik has to release a new version.  Wonder how long it would take?